# Google Maps API: Appending Data

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, append, heatmap

So I am creating a Heat Map with specific data containing lat/longs.  I am having difficulty figuring out how to append data to the heat map allowing all the data to aggregate on the heat map.  Im using setData() to refresh my Heat Map layers however is there away for me to take the data that is in the heatmap already and append the new data to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` property of a Heatmap element [is an MVCArray](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#HeatmapLayerOptions) so it should accept MVCArray methods such as push or setAt.

However, it's not clear in the documentation if there's a binding on an MVCArray rendering and its underlying data. Perhaps you will need to toggle the map property to force it to re-render. I, personally, just redeclare the data property.